# How to set the Window.Owner to Outlook window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, outlook, vsto

I have an outlook plugin which pops up a WPF window

Is there a way to set the WPF's `Window.Owner` property to Outlook?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kudos to @reedcopsey for putting us on the right track...

The trick for retrieving the **Outlook Handle** is using reflection to obtain the active window's title (*Caption*) and the `FindWindow` Win32 API to obtain the active window `IntPtr` handle (*inspector, explorer, etc.*). Inspired from [this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/6ec291f3-6f0f-4d25-aa4c-1f5779486881/). Once you have the active window handle, you can leverage [`WindowInteropHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) for managing the owner relationship.

#### Retrieving Outlook Handle (*via `ActiveWindow`*)

```cs
Window yourWPFWindow = new Window();
dynamic activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();
IntPtr outlookHwnd = new OfficeWin32Window(activeWindow).Handle;
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(yourWPFWindow);
wih.Owner = outlookHwnd;
yourWPFWindow.Show();
```

#### OfficeWin32Window (*Helper Class*)

```cs
///<summary>
/// This class retrieves the IWin32Window from the current active Office window.
/// This could be used to set the parent for Windows Forms and MessageBoxes.
///</summary>
///<example>
/// OfficeWin32Window parentWindow = new OfficeWin32Window (ThisAddIn.OutlookApplication.ActiveWindow ());   
/// MessageBox.Show (parentWindow, "This MessageBox doesn't go behind Outlook !!!", "Attention !", MessageBoxButtons.Ok , MessageBoxIcon.Question );
///</example>
public class OfficeWin32Window : IWin32Window
{

    ///<summary>
    /// The <b>FindWindow</b> method finds a window by it's classname and caption.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="lpClassName">The classname of the window (use Spy++)</param>
    ///<param name="lpWindowName">The Caption of the window.</param>
    ///<returns>Returns a valid window handle or 0.</returns>
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    #region IWin32Window Members

    ///<summary>
    /// This holds the window handle for the found Window.
    ///</summary>
    IntPtr _windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    ///<summary>
    /// The <b>Handle</b> of the Outlook WindowObject.
    ///</summary>
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _windowHandle; }
    }

    #endregion

    ///<summary>
    /// The <b>OfficeWin32Window</b> class could be used to get the parent IWin32Window for Windows.Forms and MessageBoxes.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="windowObject">The current WindowObject.</param>
    public OfficeWin32Window(object windowObject)
    {
        string caption = windowObject.GetType().InvokeMember("Caption", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, windowObject, null).ToString();

        // try to get the HWND ptr from the windowObject / could be an Inspector window or an explorer window
        _windowHandle = FindWindow("rctrl_renwnd32\0", caption);
    }
}
```

Comment: For integrating Outlook with WinForms, try using [`Forms.Show(new OfficeWin32Window(activeWindow))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) or [`Forms.ShowDialog(new OfficeWin32Window(activeWindow))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) which take the [`IWin32Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window.aspx) parameter.

Comment: What if your `yourWPFWindow ` is actually a Winforms form and not WPF?

Comment: For unmanaged windows - take a look at [`NativeWindow.AssignHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.assignhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [referenced in this related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13031316/175679). Be sure to call [`NativeWindow.ReleaseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.releasehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when your form exits.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. What I didn't realize is you still don't get the true behavior of a parent form in the sense that you have to calculate the location of the child if you want to make it display in the center of the parent.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to use this with WPF's `MessageBox.Show()` (this is different from its WinForms cousin), which takes a WPF `Window` object as the first parameter to set its owner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done via [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx):

```
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(yourWindow);
wih.Owner = outlookHwnd;
yourWindow.Show();
```

Comment: Where do you get `outlookHwnd`?

Comment: That would be the HWND of the window you want to make the parent.