# How to set window owner to an unmanaged window

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I want to set the owner form to that of an unamanged window.  I have the unmanaged window's handle.  How can I set this unmanaged window to be the owner window for my managed form?

```
IntPtr hWnd = GetUnmanagedWindow();//assume the handle is returned correctly
Form form = new Form();
form.Show(ConvertToManaged(hWnd));//Need an implementation for ConvertOrSomething()
```

Comment: Do you mean parent, or do you mean owner? They are different.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Thanks for the info.  I mean owner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use the [`NativeWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) class.

```
IntPtr hWnd = GetUnmanagedWindow();//assume the handle is returned correctly
Form form = new Form();
NativeWindow nativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
nativeWindow.AssignHandle(hWnd);
form.Show(nativeWindow);
```

As Hans points out, remember to call `ReleaseHandle` when are done with it.

Comment: So according to Hans, just add `nativeWindow.ReleaseHandle();` as last line? I tried it like this, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
public ManagedWindow ConvertToManaged(IntPtr hWnd)
{
   return new ManagedWindow(hWnd);
}

    public class ManagedWindow : IWin32Window
    {
        IntPtr _handle;
        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get { return _handle; }
        }

        public ManagedWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            _handle = handle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whilst it's easy enough to write your own implementation of `IWin32Window`, you may as well use the built in .net classes.