# Link a custom messagebox to outlook

Tags: wpf, outlook, outlook-addin, messagebox

i have realized for my outlook addin a messagebox custom.
Now, when this messagebox is shown, it's unlinked with the main window of Outlook.
How can "attach" my window with the outlook window as a normal messagebox?
Is there a property to link to windows?

-- EDIT ---

The problem is simply this:

1. Open Outlook
2. Show a custom messagebox in outlook
3. Change focus ( i open a new window such as chrome browser
4. Return to Outlook: now my messagebox is not "link" to Outlook. I want that my messagebox is displayed always when outlook window is open

Comment: You need to lay out the problem much more precisely.

Comment: Thanks for answer.The problem is simply this:
1-open Outlook
2-show a custom messagebox in outlook
3-change focus ( i open a new window such as chrome browser
4-return to Outlook: now my messagebox is not "link" to Outlook.
I want that my messagebox is displayed always when outlook window is open

Comment: I do not know the answer but it might be helpful to put these important details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved.
in the code of my messagebox i've inserted the code below:

`IntPtr hWnd = Process.GetProcessById(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id).MainWindowHandle;`
`System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper wih = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this);`

`wih.Owner = hWnd;`

as illustred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733974/how-to-set-the-window-owner-to-outlook-window)

Like this, any type of message (messagebox, generic hanlded error of your application) is "hooked" to the main application. The application is calculated by Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.

Hope that this help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The more rigorous way to retrieve the Outlook's HWND would be to cast Application.ActiveWindow (can be either Explorer or Inspector) to IOleWindow and call IOleWindow.GetWindow().