# VSTO Outlook: popup a custom notification on compose window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in and I would like to popup a notification (floating window) with a custom text message for a specific time (5 seconds for example) and then disappear automatically. I want to show this notification from within the compose window. How can I achieve this? some example will highly appreciated.

UPDATED: I would like the notification window to be a child of the compose window.

UPDATE 29.06.2022:
I have done the following:

```
   Outlook.Inspector currentInspector = this.Window as Outlook.Inspector;
    IOleWindow ioleWnd = (IOleWindow)currentInspector;
    ioleWnd.GetWindow(out IntPtr phwnd);

    NativeWindow nativeWnd = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow();
    nativeWnd.AssignHandle(phwnd);
    
    // frm is my notification window, borderless and without maximize, minimize and close buttons and without title bar.
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.ControlBox = false;
    frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;


    NativeMethods.Rect rect = new NativeMethods.Rect();
    NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(phwnd, ref rect);


    frm.Left = rect.Right - 85;
    frm.Top = rect.Bottom - 55;
    frm.Width = 80;
    frm.Height = 50;
    frm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(rect.Right - 85, rect.Bottom - 55);
    frm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
    txtBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    txtBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    txtBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
    txtBox.Visible = true;
    txtBox.Text = "This is a notification message";

    frm.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    frm.Show(nativeWnd);
```

What happens with above code is below:

1. Notification window is not positioned on the bottom right hand
   corner of the compose window.
2. If I move compose window, notification window keeps in the same position and it is not moving while I move the compose window.
3. In windows task bar it appears as the notification window is a different process/program, not being part of the same compose window, maybe I need to do something like frm.Owner = nativeWnd but it is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Windows form that closes itself automatically after a timeout.

To make your form a child of an Outlook inspector, Q/cast the `Inspector` object (e.g. from `Application.ActiveInspector`) to the `IOleWindow` interface, call `IOleWindow.GetWindow` to get the `HWND`. Create an instance of the `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow` class and call `NativeWindow.AssignHandle`. You can then pass the `NativeWindow` object to `Form.Show` or `Form.ShowModal` (`NativeWindow` object implements the `IWin32Window` interface).

Comment: How can I do the notification window to be a child of the compose window?

Comment: See the updated answer above.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try. Another thing, how can I position the child window at the bottom right corner of the compose window?

Comment: Since you know the inspector HWND, use use `GetWindowRect` Windows API function to figure out its coordinates and adjust your window position accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my post, please see it. Notification window is not positioned correctly. Also if i move compose window, notification window is not moved at the same time by keeping its position on the bottom right hand corner of the compose window. And finally in the windows task bar, notification window appears as another process/program not being part of the compose window. Could you help me please?

Comment: If you want your window to be a part of the inspector, you need to actually embed it there - you have a free floating window. To avoid showing a task bar, set ShowInTaskBar property to false. To make sure your window moves with its parent, you need to continuously monitor the parent window position (you can, for example, override its window proc or just use a timer).

Comment: Or you can just create an Outlook task pane (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) - it will be a part of the inspector and you can open/close it at will.

Comment: yeap, I considered that option as well. it would be an alternative. And why notification window is not being showing at the bottom left hand corner of the compose window? am i doing something wrong when setting frm.Location?

Comment: To make my notification window moves with its parent (compose window) i can continuously monitor the parent window (compose window) position by subscribing to the events LocationChanged and show as explained here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/331adae2-843f-4eae-bca0-8b132780a615/position-new-form-on-bottom-right-hand-corner-of-the-main-form

the problem is that in my case the NativeWindow  which is the compose window does not have those events..... so how can I subscribe to LocationChanged and Show events in this case?

Comment: Where does your window actually show? The code looks fine to me (without actually running it). You can overwrite the Inspector's window proc using `SetWindowLongPtr(HWND, GWLP_WNDPROC, , ...)`. It is fairly standard in raw Windows API, but pretty advanced in C#. Or you can call `GetWindowRect` on timer and see if the window position has changed.

Comment: My notification window is being shown outside the compose window just at the top left.

Comment: So what do you see for Location as you step through your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer which fires the `Tick` event on the main thread (UI) where you can call the `Close` method of your form. The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`'s event is raised from the UI thread by the message loop when it receives a `WM_TIMER` message. So, you are good to calling the [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method.

Note, the timer can be run and the form is closed from your code outside of the form or inside the form (built-in to the form).

Comment: How can I do the notification window to be a child of the compose window?

Comment: You must the parent window handle of your form. To do that you need to pass an instance of the `IWin32Window` interface the ctor of your form.

Comment: See [How to set the Window.Owner to Outlook window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733974/how-to-set-the-window-owner-to-outlook-window) for more information.